# How to stratify a raster object in R

Tags: r, raster, spatstat

My goal in the current work is to sumulate a database containning n variables :
(1)latitude of the location, (2)longitude of the location, (3...n-1) covariates, (n)stratum.
In stratum variable, I'm looking for the number of the compartment from which each points comes from.
But i'm struggling to get the strata.
I've created two rasters *R1* and *R2*.

```
#'Creating the window of domaine D
D <- c(300, 300)  # Square Domaine D of side 300

Win <- owin(xrange =c(0, D[1]), yrange =c(0,D[2])) 

spatstat.options(npixel=c(D[1],D[2]))

# Creating Rasters
library(raster)
# First raster
ext <- extent(Win$xrange, Win$yrange)
v1 <- rnorm(n=seq(from = -10, to=50,length.out = 100), mean = 0, sd=1)
R1 <- raster(matrix(v1,byrow=T,nrow=10, ncol=10))
extent(R1) <- ext
crs(R1) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +datum=WGS84"
names(R1) <- 'temp sim'
R1
# Second Raster
v2 <- rnorm(n=seq(from = 100, to=2000,length.out = 100), mean = 0, sd=1)
R2 <- raster(matrix(v1,byrow=T,nrow=10, ncol=10))
extent(R2) <- ext
crs(R2) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +datum=WGS84"
names(R2) <- 'precip sim'
R2
# Raster List
Rasters.group <- stack(R1, R2)
```

After doing that I've **convert the rasters into .im objects**

```
#' Creating .im objects based on the previous rasters. 
#' Each .im object will represent an environmental condition
library(maptools)
IM1 <- as.im.RasterLayer(R1)
IM1 <- as.im.RasterLayer(R2)

#We can plot them as well
library(fields)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
image.plot(list(x=IM1$xcol, y=IM1$yrow, z=IM1$v), main= "temp sim", asp=1)
image.plot(list(x=IM2$xcol, y=IM2$yrow, z=IM2$v), main= "precip sim", asp=1)
```

Now I've combined the *.im* objects in order to generate spacial points from them.

```
# Combination  of invironments

Com <- IM1 + IM1
image.plot(list(x=Com$xcol, y=Com$yrow, z=Com$v), main= "Global env", asp=1, col=c("green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "White", "Black"))

# Generating points Log - Gaussian Cox process

lgc.process <- rLGCP('matern', mu=Com, var=0.5, scale=0.05, nu=1)
lgc.process

xycoor <- cbind(lgc.process$x, lgc.process$y)

lgc.data <- cbind(xycoor, extract(Rasters.group, xycoor))
```

The following is the result:

```
> head(lgc.data)
                           temp.sim precip.sim
[1,] 194.13086 169.76961 1.82615774 1.82615774
[2,]  31.07026 271.56473 0.09453324 0.09453324
[3,] 109.21386 232.53282 2.30704591 2.30704591
[4,]  27.16373 121.88652 0.83505001 0.83505001
[5,]  97.95982 105.71822 1.85318918 1.85318918
[6,] 167.63728  61.16835 1.14231913 1.14231913
```

Now it remains the last column in which i'm expecting to see from which compatment(stratum) each of the points comes from. I need at least 10 strata.
All what I've tried donnot lead me to what i'm looking for. I've used `split` function, but I'm not getting result.

How should i do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where these strata come from. Are you subdividing the 300x300 window into smaller regions and you want to know which of the smaller regions each point comes from?

Comment: Yes that's what i'd like to do. Please help

Comment: Mr. Ege Ruban, your comment helped me to discover one of your amazing books titled: Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R. Hopefully this book will teach me a lot of thing about spatial point patterns.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things in your code that seem strange. E.g. both when you
create `v1` and `v2` you have a special vector for the argument `n`, but only
the length is used, so it is equivalent to:

```r
v1 <- rnorm(100)
v2 <- rnorm(100)
```

In the beginning you say something about longitude and latitude, but you
should be aware that spatstat only works with planar projected coordinates.
It is great to go through `sf`/`maptools`/`raster`/`stars`/`terra` if you
need to work with different projections and convert between them. In your
code in the question however you never do any of that and following code is
somewhat similar to what you do:

```r
library(spatstat)
Win <- square(300)
IM1 <- as.im(matrix(v1, 10, 10), W = Win)
IM2 <- as.im(matrix(v2, 10, 10), W = Win)
Com <- IM1 + IM1
lgc.process <- rLGCP('matern', mu=Com, var=0.5, scale=0.05, nu=1)
lgc.process # Note this has a lot of points
#> Planar point pattern: 792607 points
#> window: binary image mask
#> 10 x 10 pixel array (ny, nx)
#> enclosing rectangle: [0, 300] x [0, 300] units
```

Divide domain into nx*ny quadrats (a tessellation) and give them labels (marks)

```r
nx <- 4
ny <- 3
qtess <- quadrats(Win, nx, ny)
marks(qtess) <- 1:(nx*ny)
qtess
#> Tessellation
#> Tiles are equal rectangles, of dimension 75 x 100 units 
#> 4 by 3 grid of tiles
#> Tessellation is marked
#> window: rectangle = [0, 300] x [0, 300] units
plot(qtess) #' marks/labels not visible on this type of plot
```

[image]

Convert into a factor valued image with the mark labels as the value of each region:

```r
qim <- as.im(qtess, dimyx = c(ny, nx))
qim
#> factor-valued pixel image
#> factor levels:
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12"
#> 3 x 4 pixel array (ny, nx)
#> enclosing rectangle: [0, 300] x [0, 300] units
plot(qim, valuesAreColours = FALSE)
```

[image]

Finally extract the values of the image at the locations of the point pattern:

```r
val <- qim[lgc.process]
xycor <- coords(lgc.process)
lgc.data <- cbind(xycor, temp = IM1[lgc.process], precip = IM2[lgc.process], val = val)
head(lgc.data)
#>           x         y      temp     precip val
#> 1 260.93114 167.25626 1.6887990 -0.1590026   8
#> 2 253.33075 242.38444 2.1093809 -0.9992986   4
#> 3  23.57170 244.86029 2.3924167  0.3739248   1
#> 4  14.27467 263.48256 2.3924167  0.3739248   1
#> 5  91.47319  82.87186 1.6035174  1.8282477  10
#> 6 157.93998  26.90952 0.6159271  0.7130826  11
```